# Can you please tell me which formula this is?

Tags: probability

I am working on a recommendation system, which uses the euclidean distance formula to calculate the similarity between 2 users.

[Euclidean distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4cVH.png)

Thereafter, it uses a formula to predict the rating using this formula:
$$
p(u,i) = \frac{\sum_{N\in similarTo(i)}(S_{i,N}\times R_{u,N})}{\sum_{N\in similarTo(i)}(|S_{i,N}|)}.
$$

I cannot find the formula name anywhere. Please can you tell me what formula this is so that I can make progress on my research.

I am not a math person, so any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks similar to a Cosine Similarity (also look into Pearson Distance and Uncentered Pearson Distance)

Comment: Checked it does look similar, but doesn't look the exact. The difference is deduces the similarity, this equation deduces the probability of the rating user u will give to item i. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept looking at the formula and it looked awfully familiar. I commented that it was closely tied to the Pearson Distance which wasn't that far off. I think this is an application of **Collaborative Filtering**. More precisely **Item-based Collaborative Filtering** which is used a lot in Recommendation Systems.

If my memory serves me right that formula is the weighted summation of items that have close similarity by using a given similarity measure (Euclidean Distance, Minkowski Distance, Pearson, etc...) and after building your Item-Similarity matrix. So there's the name of that approach.

**Edit:** If, in the future, you have more questions of the like IMHO posting them on the Data Science or Cross-Validated Stack Exchange would yield a quicker response.

Comment: Found it. It was the item based collaborative filtering formula I just didn't know where to find it. I was looking everywhere. Plus I don't know how to search for formulas like this. Thanks for that! Much appreciated.